# runuser & permission denied on /dev/stdout

Tags: bash, permission-denied

I've a problem on a bash script that is:
- executed by "root" on system startup or on demand
- run a script with "stefano" priviledges
- redirect output on a log file if triggered by "root" or on "/dev/stdout" if triggered by "stefano":

```
 #!/bin/bash
 [ "$1" == "log" ] && log="$2" || log="/dev/stdout"

 if [ "`/usr/bin/whoami`" != "stefano" ]; then
      echo "You are not allowed"
      exit 9
 fi

 runuser -s /bin/bash stefano -c "echo I am Stefano >> $log"
```

In this case i obtain a `bash: /dev/stdout: Permission denied`

Why user "stefano" cannot write on /dev/stdout if command is triggered by root?

obviously acting as `stefano> echo "I am Stefano" >> /dev/stdout` does not get any error.

Thanks in advance for your help!
Stefano, Milan, Italy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why user "stefano" cannot write on /dev/stdout if command is triggered
>   by root?

That's probably because the terminal device is owned by root without write permission for others.
Try `/dev/tty` instead.

Answer (score 0):

In your if statement

```
if [ "/usr/bin/whoami" != "stefano" ]; then
```

you compare the sttring `"/usr/bin/whoami"` with the string `"stefano"` (literally), and of course it is never equal, so the expression in the if statement is always true.

You could use [command substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) to execute the command `"/usr/bin/whoami"` (returns the current user's username) like this:

```
if [ "$(/usr/bin/whoami)" != "stefano" ]; then
```

Note that this will only work when you are user "stefano", and not as root, since you validate based on the username.

Comment: yes, your're right. I made a typo/transcription error. I corrected it by the way the error I have is on "permission denied" while I'm trying to flush output on /dev/stdout